# Strange "java.io.IOException: EOF" error in Android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

My app users are reporting very strange error in Google Market, and I absolutely don't know what does it mean. Here is the error log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: EOF at
 com.google.s.a.b.b.f.a(Unknown Source) at
 com.google.s.a.b.b.f.a(Unknown Source) at
 com.google.s.a.b.b.f.g(Unknown Source) at
 com.google.s.a.b.b.f.f(Unknown Source) at
 com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.j.b.a(Unknown Source) at
 com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.j.b.b(Unknown Source) at
 com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.k.cu.<init>(Unknown Source) at
 com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.l.m.a(Unknown Source) at
 com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.l.d.a(Unknown Source) at
 com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.l.g.handleMessage(Unknown
 Source) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) at
 android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153) at
 com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.l.d.run(Unknown Source)
```

It is some Google API error or I did something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is google api's error, caused by inability to read config or temp file, it might be caused by user removing external memory while your application is working.

Comment: Oh, glad to know that it is not my fault.